# Silverlight MVVM question

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm working on a project and learning SL/MVVM as I go.  I'm using MVVM light and feel as if I have a decent grasp of things.  I understand binding controls to the VM and also sending events/commands to the VM.

A few questions I have:

In an MVVM application how is the Application object accessed from the VM, for calling Application.Install or checking install state?  Or do you just stick it in the code behind of a view for that case?  I suppose this could be done through MVVM messaging but you'd still register a listener in the code behind.

I'm not sure if this can happen but how would one, from the VM, access a method from a View/Control(s) to do something that can't be accomplished through data binding or commanding/eventing? Is this where Dependency Object/Properties come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application should provide a service for obtaining the information relevant to the `Application` singleton; as with any data which could be used throughout the application; yours or the frameworks.

If you are ever needing to access a method on a `UIElement`/`FrameworkElement`/`Control` from the ViewModel that would be the point in looking into a custom `Control` or `UserControl` to provide the needed behavior. That is typically solved via `Triggers` and `Behaviors`.

Comment: Is application providing a service generally implemented through messaging?  I could see registering and processing messages in the Application object for things such as Application.Install.

Comment: @DerekBeattie If you have the application broken apart into varying separate projects/modules; then yes a messaging framework could be used. If you were leveraging an IoC/DI framework you could inject the service within the class which cares about using that service. Under the covers that service could be registered with the container of choice to behave like a singleton...thus allowing you to add functionality onto the IApplicationService as needed or leverage the Application singleton.